# Which RAM will suit my notebook ACER Aspire 5820tg 1333MHz or 1066MHz what CAS

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade

I have my ACER Aspire 5820TG - 433G32Mn and want to upgrade RAM memory.

Currently it has the following components:

**CPU**: Intel Core i5 430M

**Mainboard**: Acer ZR7B

**RAM** (3GB): 2048MB DDR3 PC3-10700 (667MHz) Samsung M471B5673FH0-CH9 
1024MB DDR3 PC3-10700 (667MHz) Elpida EBJ10UE8BDS0-DJ-F

I replaced HDD to SSD, and want to also upgrade the RAM memory (3GB is pretty low, when using for example Android Studio, etc). I have some doubts, what parameters are needed to successfully upgrade it.
As I see, current (original) RAM is 1333MHz, and 7-7-7-20 (?). But on the intel site i see that it works with 800/1066. So it is probably underclocked.

**Which RAM will suit me? What is important? Timings must be the same? What else?**

I want to upgrade it to 6GB (leave current 2GB and buy 4GB, or buy 2x4GB, as I guess, that I can use only 2 slots)

Here are some pictures from CPU-Z:

[CPU-Z pictures of laptop components (imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJLMF.png)

Comment: The bios can limit ram speed, higher speeds can be locked out by the manufacturer (ACER), I would see what ACER says can be used in that PC before comiting to buy

Comment: I did not think that replacing the memory would be such a challenging task...
I scanned the laptop with the following result:
http://eu.crucial.com/eur/en/scanview/A2CB1CD331D926C3
They say that for instance this will suit:
DDR3 PC3-12800 • CL=11 • Unbuffered • NON-ECC • DDR3-1600 • 1.35V •
I have no idea what to do... :D

Comment: they are 2 different classifications of the same speed ram....http://www.kingston.com/us/business/server_solutions/best_practices/ddr3_1600

Comment: crucial is usually right, so it does look like you can upgrade, if you buy from crucial they guarantee it will work or your money back.

Answer (score 1):

According to your CPU specifications, [as it is also on intel's website](http://ark.intel.com/products/43537/Intel-Core-i5-430M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_26-GHz) (and as you mentioned), your laptop' CPU can support DDR3-800/1066. In this case I would recommend two memory modules, since it supports dual channel memory. And for a better performance, I would also recommend two modules with the same memory and clock speed. In this case it would be 2x4GB memory sticks. In case if the manufacturer has "unlocked" the motherboard for higher speeds (which I doubt), you can check with a tool like [HWiNFO](http://www.hwinfo.com/), what is the current memory clock for each RAM module. (On the left side, under "Memory").
If they are running at 1333MHz as your original RAM, then go on and buy a pair with that speed, otherwise buy a pair of 1066MHz.

Comment: I have used HWiNFO, and made the analysis. It is presented on screenshots: [Screenshots from HWiNFO](http://imgur.com/cZquI7p,zctsiHa,pfGKGtk,RsI8hUh,8hUZpSI,iRgRxcK)

Memories are, undoubtely, 1333MHz, but I am not sure if the actual frequency is 1066MHz or 1333MHz....
There is an overall info, that the size of memory is 3GB and Clock is ~533.1MHz = 4.00 x 133.0MHz

Comment: Don't check rows, click on the memory only, and you will see 'Current Memory Clock'. You can also click on summary, and under your gpu info (bottom right corner) you will see the current memory speed. As for another way to determine if it will actually work, check out [Crucial' System Scanner](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/systemscanner). It scans your system, and then displays the memory supported. Or you can select your laptop model on their website and see what type of memory is supported. But still, I would stay with the 1066MHz one.

Comment: If you are still unsure, you can remove all memory modules, and leave only the one with 1333MHz speed, and check out if it's really working with that speed.